# Best option to crawl a multilevel BPMN model

Tags: project-management

I have the need to explain workflows modeled in BPMN to a team. These BPMN contain call activities. To dive into a call activity I have to open the containing file, forcing me to switch between several open diagrams.

Is there a tool or browser extension that allows crawling into sub processes and call activities, making it possible to navigate seamlessly through them using linked tasks and breadcrumbs?